# How to pass 2D Array to google chart html

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have 2D array generated by google sheet script:
[Steve, 2],[Bob, 101],[Anna, 78] etc.

```
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ActivityChart'); // Modified
   t.DataForChart = (newdata_03);
   html = t.evaluate().setWidth(950).setHeight(600); // Added
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
   .showModalDialog(html,' ');
```

i need to pass it to:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],      //need to replace it with my array
      ['Work',     11],               //need to replace it with my array
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be grateful if you help, because I am very weak in html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- Your HTML and Javascript in your question is the file of `ActivityChart`.
- In your script, `newdata_03` of `t.DataForChart = (newdata_03);` is `[["Steve", 2], ["Bob", 101], ["Anna", 78],,,]`.
- You want to send this 2 dimensional array to HTML side, and use it with `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`.

For this, how about this modification? In this modification, the scriptlets are used. Please modify `ActivityChart` of your HTML & Javascript is as follows. In this case, I didn't modify the Google Apps Script side.

#### From:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],      //need to replace it with my array
  ['Work',     11],               //need to replace it with my array
  ['Eat',      2],
  ['Commute',  2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep',    7]
]);
```

#### To:

```
<? const str = JSON.stringify(DataForChart); ?>
let ar = JSON.parse(<?= str ?>);
ar.unshift(["header1", "header2"]);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ar);
```

#### Note:

- From your question, I thought that the 2 dimensional array might have no header row. So I added the header row using `ar.unshift(["header1", "header2"])`. If your data includes the header row, please remove this.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: @Vladimir Melnikov Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.